# How to use private npm packages by local development?

Tags: javascript, git, npm

My team has project and 4-5 micro services on Node.js. We have important javascript file which we use in application, but now we need to start using this file in services. 
I want to create private npm package which will represents this file.
I'll add this new package in package.json of application and services using link to the repo.
I have doubt about local development. Lets imagine that developer needs to make change into this file in separated repository and make change into application. I see this workflow:

1. Commit changes to file and push to branch "my-new-feature-001".
2. Change package.json of my application for using this branch of common file
3. Develop feature in application.
4. Merge "my-new-feature-001" into main branch of file
5. input "git checkout package.json" in application
6. Commit and merge changes in application.

It's so difficult. Is there any more simple solution? I mean using remote repository for deploy servers and local repository of common file for local development?

Comment: I personally think that we can't really answer, as it requires inside knowledge of how your app works and what development strategies you use. (Also, why is it difficult if you can list it in 6 steps?)

Comment: It's not so difficult, but I believe that there is more simple solution. We are developers and we want to automate everything :)

Comment: Well, the only steps I could see being removed are 2 and 5, but that's because I don't really understand what they do. The rest are some minor git commands.